# In UWP how do you change a style's setter in code?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to change the ActionButton style in UWP's TeachingTip.

A TeachingTip has the following attribute:

```
public Style ActionButtonStyle { get; set; }
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
mytip.ActionButtonStyle.SetValue(Button.ForegroundProperty, "Red");
```

But it fails with a System.NullReferenceException. I also tried different types of values (Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Brush and Windows.UI.Color) instead of "Red", but that all failed with the same exception.

I also tried the following:

```
var setter = mytip.ActionButtonStyle.Setters.OfType<Setter>().FirstOrDefault(X => X.Property == Control.ForegroundProperty);
setter.Value = "Red";
```

But that also failed but with a different exception - System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: updated the question with more info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue once and I managed to do it like this :
In the App.xaml file add your style

```
<Page.Resources>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Orange" Color="#F49600" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Then you can access it from anywhere in your code like this

```
Button.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["Orange"];
```

And if you want to do it with a whole style, you can do like this

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="Path">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F49600" />
</Style>
```

```
ActionButtonStyle = Application.Current.Resources["MyStyle"] as Style;
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, but this won't help as I do not have access to the button, its within the TeachingTip control

Comment: You can do the same with a complete style
I'll update my answer

Comment: Just saw you're answer, we're doing the same thing, your answer is full code and mine use xaml =P

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, here's what eventually worked:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(Button));
Setter setter = new Setter(Button.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red));
style.Setters.Add(setter);
mytip.ActionButtonStyle = style;
```